# Jersey 2 and Guice integration: where is .getServiceLocator() method

Tags: java, rest, dependency-injection, jersey, guice

I am trying to migrate an existing Rest API based on Jersey 1.19 that uses Guice for DI to Jersey 2.26. I did not find much topics online dealing with the subject. The few I came across mention that Jersey 2 has its own DI mechanism called HK2 and that a bridge needs to be created between Guice and HK2, like mentioned in this repository here: https://github.com/caberger/jerseyguice and this article here http://www.aberger.at/en/blog/design/2016/11/17/bridge-jersey2-guice.html. The example uses Jersey 2.24 and in the DI logic [here](https://github.com/caberger/jerseyguice/blob/master/src/main/java/at/aberger/jerseyguice/config/RestServletModule.java) there is this statement:

```
ServletContainer servletContainer = (ServletContainer)container;
        ServiceLocator serviceLocator = container.getApplicationHandler().getServiceLocator();
        GuiceBridge.getGuiceBridge().initializeGuiceBridge(serviceLocator);
        GuiceIntoHK2Bridge guiceBridge = serviceLocator.getService(GuiceIntoHK2Bridge.class);
        Injector injector = (Injector) servletContainer.getServletContext().getAttribute(Injector.class.getName());
        guiceBridge.bridgeGuiceInjector(injector);
```

The problem is that the `container.getApplicationHandler().getServiceLocator();` statement does not work anymore because the method `.getServiceLocator()` has been removed from Jersey 2.24 to 2.26 without any mention.

If anybody has any insight on how to do the same action or has a different idea on how to wire Guice to Jersey 2.26, that would be really appreciated.

Comment: I found this: `ServiceLocator serviceLocator = (ServiceLocator) servletContainer.getServletContext().getAttribute(ServletProperties.SERVICE_LOCATOR);` but it is throwing an NPE.

Comment: Stumbled upon the same issue, do you have an update?

Comment: I found a workaround without using guice bridge, I am gonna post it as an answer later on.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up not using `jerseyguice` bridge. I am posting an answer to my own question, maybe this this will help somebody. What I did is using `com.google.inject.Inject` in all the services, and the reason for this is that `com.google.inject.Inject` is not catched by HK2. For all the resource classes (annotated with `@Path`), I used `javax.inject.Inject` annotation. I kept my original Guice module, and then I created a bridge HK2 module:

```
  @ApplicationPath("/app")
public class Application extends ResourceConfig {

 public Application() {
    packages("com.app");
   Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(
     new MyOriginalGuiceModule(),
     new MyOriginalGuiceModule2());

   register(new HK2BridgeModule(injector));
  }
}
```

and then :

```
public class HK2BridgeModule extends AbstractBinder {

  private final Injector guiceInjector;

  public HK2BridgeModule(Injector guiceInjector) {
    this.guiceInjector = guiceInjector;
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure() {

    //Here are only the services needed by the resources, they are pulled from guice injector using the factory
    bindFactory(new ServiceFactory<Service1>(guiceInjector, Service1.class)).to(Service1.class);
    //...all your services here
  }

  //this will allow HK2 to pull dependencies from guice injector
  private static class ServiceFactory<T> implements Factory<T> {

    private final Injector guiceInjector;

    private final Class<T> serviceClass;

    public ServiceFactory(Injector guiceInjector, Class<T> serviceClass) {

      this.guiceInjector = guiceInjector;
      this.serviceClass = serviceClass;
    }

    @Override
    public T provide() {
      return guiceInjector.getInstance(serviceClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(T versionResource) {
    }
  }
}
```

It does the job.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need Guice-HK2 bridge in order to integrate Guice and Jersey. Here is the web server implementation without bridge -
https://github.com/sorskod/webserver.

However, if you still want to use bridge, note that starting from Jersey 2.26 you need to explicitly provide DI implementation, and currently only HK2 is fully supported. Maybe adding `jersey-hk2` can you help rid of exceptions.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
    <version>2.26</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thanks, but this invloves embedding the server, I am deploying on tomcat.